# How to effectively work with events generated from within a Listview's datatemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I've the following data template within a listview and a few tapped events
in it (XAML of it below). In order to hide/show the visibility of an item within the data template, I'm using the logic below (determining my original source) to identify which control within the listview has invoked an event. The problem I'm seeing with this approach is that, even for slightest of changes in the data template, I'm changing my event logic in determining the right children. Is there an efficient logic that could be used so that everytime I change the layout, I don't have to touch the code behind?

**XAML**

```
  <DataTemplate x:DataType="filter:FilterCategory">
     <!--<RelativePanel>-->
     <Grid Name="FilterHeaders">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Name="Header" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="20,10,0,0" Text="{x:Bind NameAlias}" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <RelativePanel Grid.Column="1">
           <TextBlock Name="DownArrow" Text="&#xE70D;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="8" 
                    Visibility="{x:Bind IsCollapsed}" Grid.Column="1" Tapped="DownArrow_Tapped" 
                    RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
           <TextBlock Name="UpArrow" Text="&#xE70E;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="8" 
                    Visibility="{x:Bind IsExpand}" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" Tapped="UpArrow_Tapped" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
        </RelativePanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=UpArrow,Path=Visibility}">
           <ListView SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{x:Bind FilterCategoryItems}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
              <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                 <TransitionCollection/>
              </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
              <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                 <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
                 </Style>
              </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
              <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate x:DataType="filter:FilterCategoryItem">
                    <Grid>
                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <CheckBox x:Name="FilterCheckBoxTask" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStylePlainView}" IsThreeState="False" 
                                Opacity="0.2" MinWidth="10"/>
                       <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind NameAlias}"/>
                    </Grid>
                 </DataTemplate>
              </ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <!--<ListView.FooterTemplate>
                                   <DataTemplate>
                                      <Grid>
                                         <Button x:Name="LoadMore" Tag="{x:Bind Name}" Content="Load More" Click="LoadMore_Click" Visibility="Visible"/>
                                      </Grid>
                                   </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.FooterTemplate>-->
           </ListView>
           <loading:LoadingControl Name="LoadingControl" IsShowGrid="{Binding IsShowResultGrid,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                   IsShowProgressRing="{Binding IsShowProgressRing,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                   ShowDisplayMessage="{Binding DisplayMessage,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Grid>
     </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void DownArrow_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource is TextBlock textBlock)
            {
                textBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                if (textBlock.Parent is Grid grid)
                {
                    if (grid.Children[2] is TextBlock textBlck)
                        textBlck.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }

        private void UpArrow_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource is TextBlock textBlock)
            {
                textBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                if (textBlock.Parent is Grid grid)
                {
                    if (grid.Children[1] is TextBlock textBlck)
                        textBlck.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Behaviors SDK by refer to here: [XamlBehaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/)

After you've installed the nuget packages, you can use the following code:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="mytext" Text="1" Grid.Column="0">
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                        <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=mytext}" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBlock>
```

For more details, you can refer to this [doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/EventTriggerBehavior).

Well I need to admit that this may not satisfy all your needs. Actually you cannot know this line: grid.Children is TextBlock textBlck. I will think about using binding and converter later when I have time. But behaviors SDK is a direction for you in my mind. Please give it a look first.

Comment: Thank you @Barry Wang. That helped !! (y)